# Error when loading new changes

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh

Over the last couple of days I've noticed a problem with the banner popup that says there's been changes to the post your viewing.

Clicking the banner doesn't seem to apply any changes to the page and today I was able to capture an error in the console

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"Html":" ... ","VotesCastJson":[]}

The `Html` part seems to contain the post contents.

The problem is that the code making the request expects a straight HTML response and not JSON

```js
jQuery.get(url, "html").done(data => {
  const $doc = $(data) // this causes the error
```

Comment: Already reported and [meta-tag:status-review] on MSE: [Loading posts in real time is broken in some cases due to a breaking change in the format data is returned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376823/289905).

Comment: Cheers @SebastianSimon, the search functions around here are terrible

Comment: I'll grant you that the built-in search is terrible, but even if it were not terrible, it still wouldn't have found that Q&A on a completely different site. :-)

Comment: I got a bit frustrated with this not working, so I've added a userscript which patches this issue as an [answer to: "Loading posts in real time is broken in some cases due to a breaking change in the format data is returned"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377027/271271).

Comment: @CodyGray I searched on MSE too

Comment: @Phil Try Google search instead. I used `site:meta.stackexchange.com "an edit has been made" after:2022-02-01` and found it immediately.

Comment: @wjandrea using the on-site search was my mistake. I do use Google for finding StackOverflow posts

Comment: Honestly, Google search with `site:meta.stackexchange.com` or `site:meta.stackoverflow.com` does very often lead to irrelevant results, to such a degree, that the on-site search is often _better_. I’m just glad that there is now a potential duplicate target on MSO as well as MSE. I only commented two minutes after your post because I anticipated multiple duplicates for this bug (although yours was the first one after four days, and there hasn’t been a new one since), so I watched Meta closely and was prepared to link to the original very quickly.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I appreciate your diligence

Comment: This appears to have been fixed recently.

Comment: This was fixed on Monday, see [my answer on the MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377629/718314)