# Refreshing via "An edit has been made to this post" broken

Tags: bug

When a question has been edited while viewing it, the "An edit has been made to this post" banner appears. Clicking on it does nothing; the banner just disappears, but the question does not refresh. Instead, this error appears in the browser console:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"Html":"            \r\n<div class=\"question\" data-questionid=\"71436469\" data-position-on ...
```

With this trace:

[image: stack stace]

Browser: macOS Safari 15.3

Comment: Already reported and [meta-tag:status-review]: [Error when loading new changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416489/4642212). On MSE: [Loading posts in real time is broken in some cases due to a breaking change in the format data is returned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376823/289905).

Comment: This appears to have been fixed recently.